# Apigee Api proxy - how to make asynchronous call

Tags: api, asynchronous, proxy, response, apigee

I have api that I would like to return to user as soon as the message is received by apigee. Do not wait for response from my service. Do you know how to do that using apigee api proxy?

Comment: Try building a Node.js proxy, in which you can return an immediate (asynchronous) response and send another request afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the answear. What I did at the moment is created js as resource with get() to my destination and attached it to my endpoint. After that I attached raisefault to return as fast as possible to the user, so on trace as I see around 8ms for response. However I will check node.js as you @r3mus proposed as it seems it might be a correct solution and not so "hacky work around" as I did.

Answer (score 3):

The node.js method mentioned above is probably the most straight forward solution.  Information on using node.js with Apigee can be found at http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/developing-nodejs-applications-apigee-edge

Answer (score 1):

I believe you tried the initial right approach Kaszaq using httpClient get method. As it's been documented in Apigee Docs.

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/javascript-object-model

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/blob/master/sample-proxies/async-callout/apiproxy/resources/jsc/callout.js

And yes, if you want a more robust solution try Node.js.

```
//
//  Make 5 HTTP callouts to Yahoo weather to get the weather for 5 cities 
//  The calls are all asynchronous and execute in parallel
//  httpClient returns an exchange object that will contain the HTTP response. . . when it arrives
//

var paloAlto = httpClient.get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2467861'); 
context.session['paloAlto'] = paloAlto;

var anchorage = httpClient.get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2354490'); 
context.session['anchorage'] = anchorage;

var honolulu = httpClient.get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2423945');
context.session['honolulu'] = honolulu;

var newyork = httpClient.get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2459115');
context.session['newyork'] = newyork;

var dublin = httpClient.get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=560743');
context.session['dublin'] = dublin;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have the liberty of customising API's using Node.js. You can use that to implement async behaviour in you api proxy.

For more info on customising api's using Node.js visit the following link-
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/developing-nodejs-applications-apigee-edge